# kubectl bash completion for alias with options

Tags: alias, kubectl, bash-completion

I have several kubectl aliases configured:

```
alias k='kubectl'
alias kn='kubectl -n'
alias ks='kubectl -n kube-system'
alias ka='kubectl get --all-namespaces'
```

Bash completion works fine for `kubectl` and I got it working for most of the aliases as well by calling

```
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl $alias
```

This does however not work for the `ka` alias - the completion ignores that the `get` is already part of the alias and completes the command as if it wasn't there.

Is it possible to configure the completion to also work for the `ka` alias?

OS is a docker container using Ubuntu 16:04 as base image.

Comment: It does not work even if we add an alias as `alias k='KUBECONFIG=~/my.yaml kubectl'` this is technically not **kubectl alias with options**. This question should be like *dynamic bash completions do not work for kubectl aliases*

Answer (score 1):

**When aliasing kubectl use = options**

From https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/31824#issue-1146171318

> Setting flags/options in your alias requires the = format

Hence aliases should be created as follows:

```
alias k='kubectl'
alias kn='kubectl --namespace='
alias ks='kubectl --namespace=kube-system'
alias ka='kubectl --all-namespaces get'
alias kp="kubectl --kubeconfig=~/.kube/production.kubeconfig --namespace=prod"

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", 
GitVersion:"v1.23.5", 
GitCommit:"c285e781331a3785a7f436042c65c5641ce8a9e9", 
GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-03-16T15:58:47Z", 
GoVersion:"go1.17.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```